# whats the correct way to paste from registers in insert mode?

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

Title says it all really, trying to get the CTRL-R {register} while in insert mode of regular vim working in emacs with evil mode

Comment: `C-r a` pastes the contents of register `a` in insert mode for me. What does `C-h C-r` in insert mode report for you? For me it says "C-r runs the command evil-paste-from-register".

Comment: wtf it seems to be working for me today......maybe I was being dumb and was doing C-r C-register by mistake. Thank-you.